# why do we use 'app' variable to call the express function

Tags: node.js, express

My question is: Why do we use only the variable name 'app' to store the return of the function express and why not other variables? Express is a module in node, how can it be a function? Please help me as I am new to node.js! The following code is an example of a very basic route.

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
}
```

Comment: You should rather read or watch a tutorial of Javascript and NodeJS. This are very basic questions, which gets answered better there than here.

Comment: why dont we access the get methods by express.get() instead of app.get()?

Comment: To use `express`, you create an instance of the express library.  You do that by calling `express()` and it returns an object which popular convention names `app`, but you can name it anything you want.  Note, it is possible to have multiple servers in the same piece of code, each that is their own instance of express (app1, app2, app3, etc...).  Folks who listen on both http and https often do this.  So you need an INSTANCE of the express object before you can call `.get()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name you choose is arbitrary. `app` is chosen by convention.

In node you can export a function from a module. For example:

*test_mod.js*:

```
function test() {
   console.log("Testing")
}

module.exports = test
```

*test.js*:

```
var t = require('./test_mod')
t()
```

Comment: why dont we access the get methods by express.get() instead of app.get()?

Answer (score 2):

To use the `express` library, you create an instance of the express library.  You do that by calling `express()` and it returns an object which popular convention names `app`, but you can name it anything you want.

```
const express = require('express');     // load express library
const app = express();                  // call express factory to create
                                        // an instance of the express library
```

You can name the variable `app` anything you want.  The name `app` is used by popular convention, but you could just as easily have done:

```
const express = require('express');
const myApp = express();

myApp.get('/', ...);
```

Note, one of the reasons express requires you to create an instance is that it is possible to have multiple servers in the same piece of code, each that is their own instance of express (app1, app2, app3, etc...).  If it didn't require you to create an instance somehow and was only using module-level state for all state, then you could only ever have one server per node.js process which is more limiting than need be.

Folks who listen on both http and https often have two servers in the same app.  Or you may serve web pages on one port and serve an API on another port.  So the designers of the Express library designed it so that you need an INSTANCE of the express object before you can call `.get()` on it (thus allowing one to have multiple and completely separate instances) and the express library has offered a factory function `express()` you can call to create that instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can all it anything instead of an app, we call this app because in node.js application we create different apps for different purposes.
Please see this for more details, this is very helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27599657/9211830

Also I will suggest that you should watch some tutorials of Node.js and Express.

Answer (score 0):

App is define as variable types as object or instance of express class,We are able to use another variable name of it as, `route = express()`