# What's the difference between var express = require('express'); and var app = express();?

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

```
   'use strict';
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
```

I would have thought the 3rd line would be var app = express;
since it was declared as a variable (object) above.

The second question is from where express() function is coming?
If it is coming from express module then the third line should be

```
var app = express.express();
```

Can someone clear this up? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var express = require('express'); var app = express(), What is express()?? is it a method or a constructor? Where does it come from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599614/var-express-requireexpress-var-app-express-what-is-express-is-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have thought the 3rd line would be var app = express; since it was declared as a variable (object) above.

`require('express')` returns the [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that, when called, returns an *instance* of the Express framework.

In fact you can have multiple *express* instances if you want;

```
var express = require('express');
var server1 = express();
var server2 = express();
```

Not saying that you should but you can.

It's the exact same concept as this:

```
var dog = function(name) {
  return {
    name: name
  }
}

var jack = dog('jack');
var brad = dog('brad');
```