# cannot GET /add in node.js

Tags: node.js

```
const express=require('express');

const router=express.Router();
router.get('/add',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST"><input type="text" name="title"><button type="submit">Add</button></input></form>');
});
router.post('/product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports=router;`
```

here I am not able to get the router.get() in the browser

Comment: How r u calling the route???

Comment: Add this to your code app.use('/', router);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the following changes:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const router=express.Router();
router.get('/add',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST"><input type="text" name="title"><button type="submit">Add</button></input></form>');
});
router.post('/product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
});
app.use('/', router);
module.exports=router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the "express()", Calls the express function "express()" and puts new Express application inside the app variable (to start a new Express application).

It's something like you are creating an object of a class. Where "express()" is just like class and app is it's newly created object.

```
const app=express();
```

source and More info:

[How to use express stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599614/var-express-requireexpress-var-app-express-what-is-express-is-it)

and finally `app.use('/', route);`

This is used as a shortcut to the Router to define multiple requests on a route.